# Grouping css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to group two selectors so that an element is matched only if both selectors are satisfied?  For example, if I want the element to satisfy both the selectors `.a>.b~.c` and `.d~.e`, is it possible to write a selector that matches the intersection of these selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do set intersection in CSS selectors.  Sometimes you can find a way to combine two selectors into one that solves your specific problem, but I don't think there's a way to combine your two sample selectors.

Comment: Given OP's sample selectors, it should be possible due to the nature of the `>` and `~` combinators; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using class selectors as in your example, you can chain classes like this:

```
.a > .b.d ~ .c.e
```

> Selects an element that has both `class="c e"`
>   which is a sibling of (i.e. comes, directly or not, after) an element that has both `class="b d"`
>   which is a child of some element of `class="a"`

Or, like this, if you want `.c.e` to occur after an element that has *either* class `b` or `d`:

```
.a > .b ~ .c.e, .a > .d ~ .c.e
```

> Selects an element that has both `class="c e"`
>   which is a sibling of an element with either `class="b"` or `class="d"` (or both)
>   which is a child of some element of `class="a"`

Both selectors imply that `.b`, `.d` and `.c.e` are all children of `.a`. I should also think it gives you the class selector intersection that you're looking for.

Comment: Nothing in @ccy's post implies that `.d` is a child of `.a`.  In fact, something could match both selectors with `.a` being either a descendant or ancestor of `.d`.

Comment: @Jacob Since the target element matches both selectors then that implies that it has both c and e classes, and from that it follows that both b and d are older siblings, and that a is their parent.

Comment: @Jacob: Exactly what Neil said. Remember, the OP wants an intersection of both selectors; the key element has to have both classes `.c` and `.e`.

Answer (score 1):

I think BoltClock is on the right lines but to match exactly both the selectors given you need

```
.a > .b ~ .d ~ .c.e, .a > .b.d ~ .c.e, .a > .d ~ .b ~ .c.e {
}
```

since we have no information as to the relative positioning of b and d.

Comment: `.a > .b ~ .c.e, .a > .d ~ .c.e` would satisfy all of them methinks. Note that `~` means `.c.e` doesn't have to immediately follow `.b` or `.d`, unlike `+`.

Comment: I know, but .c.e still has to follow both .b and .d in an unspecified order.